# Polygon layer symbology not displaying correctly in QGIS 3

Tags: polygon, symbology, qgis-3, color-ramp

I have a polygon layer with multiple attributes. I want to display a color ramp for one of those fields (which is a "real" number field calculated using 2 of the other fields).

The problem is, when I set the colors (which display fine in the "symbology tab", see first picture), they do not appear on my layer's rendering. It seems that the color for the highest value is displayed for every polygon instead of the chosen color ramp.

The display works fine for any other field, except this one (second picture).

Has something like that occured for anyone?

[image: color ramp display for the target attribute, all yellow]
[image: color ramp display for another random attribute]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is that you use a  categorized symbology, if the polygons with low value (blue symbol) are very small and/or not frequent you may not be able to see them without zooming on them.

You could try using a graduated symbology (at first with a low number of classes) to see if that improve the rendering, if not at last we will know that the problem is somewhere else (and, as a side note, I think that with the kind of data you seem to have (lot of polygons, symbology on a numerical value...) the graduated symbology that sort your polygons in different classes may be more appropriate)

Comment: Many thanks, using the "Graduated" symbology instead of "Categorized" did the trick.

Comment: i'd also recommend removing black borders - either make them transparent or zero width. that makes it easier to see smaller areas' colours.